# Enable-AzDataCollection error while opening azure powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

I am getting the following error while connecting the azure powershell and everytime I run command I get error reading or writing history file. Please can someone help me on this.

Here is error i'm getting when I open the azure powershell.

Enable-AzDataCollection: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:215
Line |
215 |          Az.Accounts\Enable-AzDataCollection -WarningAction SilentlyCo …
|          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Read-only file system : '/home/nitika/.Azure/PSConfig.json'

Answer (score 0):

> Note: If it was already working but in recent days, it gives error means try to use the old version which you are used on earlier.

You can try to ***uninstall*** and ***install*** the Latest **Az.Accounts** Module.

Use `Get-Command` to list the Module commands and its version.

```
# Use the Get-command to get the module commands 
Get-Command -Module Az.Accounts
```

[image]

***Uninstall and install the Latest Module.***

```
Install-Module -Name Az

# uninstall the Az.Accounts Module
Uninstall-Module -Name Az.Accounts -AllVersions

# install the Az.Accounts 
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
```